# Auto Mapper throwing ReflectionTypeLoadException on System.Web.IHttpModule

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, automapper

I am trying to use Auto Mapper on .Net Core 2.2.

Configuration:

```
services.AddAutoMapper(cfg =>
            {                                
                cfg.CreateMissingTypeMaps = false;                
                cfg.ReplaceMemberName("_", "");
                cfg.ShouldMapProperty = pi => pi.PropertyType != typeof(List<>);
                cfg.CreateMap<bool, string>().ConvertUsing(b => b ? "Y" : "N");
                cfg.CreateMap<string, bool>().ConvertUsing(s => s == "Y");
                cfg.CreateMap<NuCoreAppUser, APP_USER>()
                .ForMember(d => d.APP_USER_ID, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.Id))
                .ReverseMap();               
            };
```

It's only a single mapping now for testing.  It works fine locally but when deployed to an Azure App Service it throws:

```
ReflectionTypeLoadException: Unable to load one or more of the requested types.
 Could not load type 'System.Web.IHttpModule' from assembly 'System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
System.Reflection.RuntimeModule.GetTypes(RuntimeModule module)
System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.get_DefinedTypes()
AutoMapper.ServiceCollectionExtensions+<>c.<AddAutoMapperClasses>b__14_2(Assembly a)
System.Linq.Enumerable+SelectManySingleSelectorIterator<TSource, TResult>.ToArray()
System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> source)
AutoMapper.ServiceCollectionExtensions.AddAutoMapperClasses(IServiceCollection services, Action<IServiceProvider, IMapperConfigurationExpression> configAction, IEnumerable<Assembly> assembliesToScan)
AutoMapper.ServiceCollectionExtensions.AddAutoMapper(IServiceCollection services, Action<IMapperConfigurationExpression> configAction)
NuCoreWebBase.Startup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) in Startup.cs
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.ConventionBasedStartup.ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.EnsureApplicationServices()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.Initialize()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.BuildApplication()
```

I can't find anywhere I reference System.Web in my app and I can't find a way to restrict Auto Mapper from scanning this assembly.

If I remove Auto Mapper everything works fine deployed.

Comment: Check your using reference, where did you use `System.Web`? Is there any mini demo to reproduce your issue?

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Dependency-injection.html#asp-net-core

Comment: @TaoZhou I searched the whole project and didn't find it anywhere which is what is so confusing.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue when trying to run unit tests locally. The following steps worked for me:

1. Check framework references (my test project was using a different framework version)
2. Align nuget packages (I had missing packages in the test project)
3. Add the following property to the unit test project file

Inside project file:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>
</PropertyGroup>
```

step 3 finally sorted it, but not sure if it will work without the previous steps.